# iframe onload function not getting called, if set src="**.html" in firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, iframe, angular-ui-grid

iframe onload function not getting called, if set src="**.html" in firefox. When removed, document can't find div in chrome.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function on_load(iframe) {
      var element = document.getElementById('myuigrid');
      var scope = angular.element(element).scope();
      if (scope != null) {
        scope.setViewModel(myuigriddata);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<!-- src="**.html" removed,document.getElementById('myuigrid') returned null; -->
<!-- if not, firefox can't call onload method -->

<body>
  <iframe style="display:none" onload="on_load(this)"></iframe>
  <div id="myuigrid" ng-if="!refresh" ui-grid="gridOptions">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: a quick workaround like below; waiting for better answers

Comment: var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('myuigrid')).scope();
      if(scope===undefined){
        iframe.src = "..."
      }
      if (scope != null) {
        scope.setViewModel(myuigrid);
      }